# How to implement google smart lock one tap sign in

Tags: google-identity

I want to implement Google's One tap sign-up and automatic sign-in in my website with the help of documentation https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/ but I am getting confused on how to implement in python.

```
def smartlock(request):
    try:
        CLIENT_ID='*******'
        csrf_token_cookie = self.request.cookies.get('g_csrf_token')
        if not csrf_token_cookie:
            webapp2.abort(400, 'No CSRF token in Cookie.')
        csrf_token_body = self.request.get('g_csrf_token')
        if not csrf_token_body:
            webapp2.abort(400, 'No CSRF token in post body.')
        if csrf_token_cookie != csrf_token_body:
            webapp2.abort(400, 'Failed to verify double submit cookie.')
        # Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
        idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(csrf_token_cookie, requests.Request(), CLIENT_ID)

        # Or, if multiple clients access the backend server:
        # idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request())
        # if idinfo['aud'] not in [CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3]:
        #     raise ValueError('Could not verify audience.')

        if idinfo['iss'] not in ['accounts.google.com', 'https://accounts.google.com']:
            raise ValueError('Wrong issuer.')

        # If auth request is from a G Suite domain:
        # if idinfo['hd'] != GSUITE_DOMAIN_NAME:
        #     raise ValueError('Wrong hosted domain.')

        # ID token is valid. Get the user's Google Account ID from the decoded token.
        userid = idinfo['sub']
    except ValueError:
        # Invalid token
        pass
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the 'Key Point' section of [this page](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/verify-google-id-token): The ID token is returned in the credential field, instead of the g_csrf_token field.

So, you need to get the idinfo with the code as below:

```python
credential = self.request.get('credential')

idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(credential, requests.Request(), CLIENT_ID)
```

The g_csrf_token parameter is for different purpose. It makes sure the request was submitted from a page in your own domain, so as to prevent the cross-site-request-forge attacks.